# Random variable is injective

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to solve the following problem on random variables and when they are injective:

> Let $X$ be a R.V. over $((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1),\lambda)$, where $\mathcal{B}(0,1)$ is the Borel set over (0,1) and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Show that $X$ is injective if and only if for every $r\in(0,1):\{r\}\in\sigma(X)$.

Here is my proof for one direction:

$\Rightarrow:$ Suppose $X$ is injective. Let $r\in(0,1)$. Since $X$ is a r.v.: $\sigma(X)=X^{-1}(\mathcal{B_\mathbb{R}})$. We'll write: $X(r)=s\rightarrow r\in X^{-1}(\{s\})$. Because X is injective: $\{r\}=X^{-1}(\{s\})$. Also $\{s\}\in\mathcal{B_\mathbb{R}}$. Hence, $\{r\}=X^{-1}(\{s\})\in X^{-1}(\mathcal{B_\mathbb{R}})=\sigma(X)$

I'm stuck on the other direction. I've to proove by contradiction but I don't know how to progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $X$ is not injective. Then there exist $r_1,r_2\in(0,1)$ such that $r_1\neq r_2$ and $X(r_1)=X(r_2)=:s\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $\{r_1\}\in\sigma(X)$, there exists $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $X^{-1}(A)=\{r_1\}$. This can only be the case if $s\in A$. But then it follows that $r_2\in X^{-1}(A)$, which is a contradiction to $X^{-1}(A)=\{r_1\}$ since $r_1\neq r_2$.